# Run gitlab-ci.yml on merge request / nothing happen

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab.ci.yml to check json files:

```
test:
    stage: test
    image: darrylb/jsonlint
    script:
      - for jsonfile in json/*.json; do jsonlint "$jsonfile"; done;
    only:
        changes:
            - json/*
    only:
        - merge_requests
```

I want to run it automatically on every merge request to my master branch.
But nothing happens, no pipeline is started, when I create a merge request.
What did I miss?

Comment: Did you check [Requirements and limitations of merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#requirements-and-limitations)?

Comment: you have "only: changes: - json/*", does the MR include changes to files in the `json` folder? 
On a side note, only: - merge_requests will do it on all MRs not just master. I suggest reviewing [only yaml docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your two `only` keywords together to one, like this:

```
test:
    stage: test
    image: darrylb/jsonlint
    script:
      - for jsonfile in json/*.json; do jsonlint "$jsonfile"; done;
    only:
      refs:
        - merge_requests
      changes:
        - json/*
```

Here is the dock that describe how you have to write it:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-onlychanges-with-pipelines-for-merge-requests

You might have to change `json/*` to `json/**/*` if you want it to trigger on all changes in all subfolders and not only the files directly in the folder `json`.